# JS get element from list by attribute

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a list:

```
navigation: [
        {
          title: "Überblick",
          icon: "mdi-view-dashboard",
          active: false,
          id: 0,
        },
        {
          title: "Persönliche Daten",
          icon: "mdi-clipboard-account-outline",
          active: false,
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          title: "Adressen",
          icon: "mdi-map-marker",
          active: true,
          id: 2,
        },
        {
          title: "Letzte Bestellungen",
          icon: "mdi-clipboard-text-multiple",
          active: false,
          id: 3,
        },
        {
          title: "Merkliste",
          icon: "mdi-playlist-star",
          active: false,
          id: 4,
        },
      ],
```

From that list I would like to only get the element with `active: true`

How can I do that, without many if statementy after each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const activeList = navigation.filter(n => n.active)
```

You will get a list of `active` elements; If none matched, it will be `[]` (empty array);

Answer (score 0):

Use easily the filter method like this.

```js
const navigation = [
  {
    title: "Überblick",
    icon: "mdi-view-dashboard",
    active: false,
    id: 0,
  },
  {
    title: "Persönliche Daten",
    icon: "mdi-clipboard-account-outline",
    active: false,
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    title: "Adressen",
    icon: "mdi-map-marker",
    active: true,
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    title: "Letzte Bestellungen",
    icon: "mdi-clipboard-text-multiple",
    active: false,
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    title: "Merkliste",
    icon: "mdi-playlist-star",
    active: false,
    id: 4,
  },
];

const active = navigation.filter((elem)=>elem.active);

console.log(active);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Example:

```
const numbers = [ -2, -4, -1, 5, -3, 8, -7];
const negativeNumbers = numbers.filter(number => number < 0);

console.log(negativeNumbers); // -2, -4, -1, -3, -7
```